# Using c++ 20 Concept to check if a function returns a const value

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to use concepts in order to be able to detect if a given type's begin function returns an iterator to "const T&" or just to "T&". But I'm not sure how one would best go about it, I have tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <typename T>
concept IsConst = std::is_const<T>::value;

template<typename T>
concept IsIterableOfConst = requires (T& t) { { *t.begin() } -> IsConst; };

template <IsIterableOfConst T>
void test()
{
    std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test()
{
    std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test<std::set<int>>();
    test<std::vector<int>>();
}
```

This produces the output "No No" when I would expect it to produce the output "Yes No" as iterators in std::set should, as far as I'm aware, always iterate over "const" versions of the sets held type. How do I correctly detect that the container contains const values?

Comment: "*How do I correctly detect that the container contains const values?*" I don't know why this is a useful thing to ask of a range. If the function you're constraining is not going to do any modifications of the elements, why should it care if the range is const or not? Functions that take an argument by `const &` can still be called if you have non-constant lvalues, after all. Why should that not be true of ranges?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direct issue here is that `decltype((*t.begin()))` for `std::set<int>` gives you the type `int const&`, and the type trait `std::is_const<T>` checks if `T` is some type `U const`. A reference is not const.

You need to strip the reference first:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept IsConst = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

---

That said, this isn't really a completely correct check for const-ness. Consider the range `views::iota(0, 10)` which gives you a bunch of integers on demand. The reference type of this range is `int` (not `int&`, not `int const&`, just `int`). This is *not* a `const` type, so your concept would say that such a range does not model `IsIterableOfConst` (side-note: the term is range, not iterable). But such a range really is const - you cannot modify the contents of it.

So a closer answer would be:

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_suitably_const = true;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_suitably_const<T&> = is_const_v<T>;

template <typename R>
concept RangeOfConst = range<R> && is_suitably_const<range_reference_t<R>>;
```

This would say that `vector<int>` is not a `RangeOfConst`, `set<int>` and `vector<int> const` are, as is `iota_view<int>`.

But... it would also say that `vector<bool>` is a `RangeOfConst`, even though you *can* modify those! I'll leave that one as something to ponder for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The direct way is that if `T` is const, then `T` should be of the same type as `add_const_t<T>`, so you just need to change your `IsConst` to

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept IsConst = std::is_same_v<T, std::add_const_t<T>>;
```

Comment: Could also just use `T const` instead of `std::add_const_t<T>`